# HttpContext.Request.ContentLength is always 0 for PUT? (But valid for POST)

Tags: iis, webdav, httpmodule

My website accepts files for upload. Files can be uploaded via WebDAV (PUT) or via POST. For POSTs, my HttpModule intercepts the request and saves the BODY of the POST to a file on the server. For PUTs, WebDAV handles the creation of the file.

My HttpModule also logs every file upload in its OnEndRequest event handler.

I'm finding that FOR PUTs (WebDAV) both

```
 ctx.Request.Headers["Content-Length"]
 ctx.Request.ContentLength
```

are always equal to zero, although for POSTs both of these contain the length of the body content.

What do I need to do to get the length of a file uploaded via WebDAV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was writing this up I realized that for a PUT, I know the name of the file which is PUT to the server. So I solved this issue with the following code:

```
  if (ctx.Request.ContentLength == 0)
  {
      if (ctx.Request.HttpMethod == "PUT")
      {
          FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ctx.Items["OutFile"].ToString());
          fileSize = fi.Length;
      }
  }
  else
  {
      fileSize = ctx.Request.ContentLength;
  }
```

(Where ctx.Items["OutFile"] is the name of the file which I have preserved from a previous event handler.)

So this is working for me now. Still and all, it would be nice to be able to get this info without having to go out to the filesystem. If you know how I can get it from the context of the currently executing http transaction, I will be grateful for your advice.